# Implementing Loading indicator without using multi threading

Tags: c#, xamarin

Is there a way to implement a loading indicator when a certain process is running without using Task.Run?

Comment: Make a function that updates the visual indicator based on a percentage. Call it after you load a file or portion of a file to update it.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin Forms, you can bind the [IsVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.isvisible?view=xamarin-forms) property of the loading indicator to a property on your view model.

If you are using Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS then it would be a little bit more work. For Xamarin.Android for instance you would bind to the [Visibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.views.view.visibility?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12) property on an Android `View` but would need a custom converter to convert from Boolean values to the Android Visibility values `Visibile` or `Invisible`